# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'code' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app runs perfectly on my local server but returns the error below when I try to push it to heroku:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'code' for nil:NilClass)
```

The method `'code'` is the title of the first column in my SQLite database and is used to search for products in a search bar which are then graphed on my app.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Please provide the complete logs for that exception. Are sure that the product is loaded in that view?

Comment: Thanks. The complete logs is very long. I don't think the view is the problem as it works fine on my local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to tell without seeing any code, but more than likely, somewhere you're doing

`some_variable.code`

and this variable is nil. What's probably happening is that you haven't added data into your production database (on Heroku) that you have in your development (local) database, which is causing this variable to be `nil` on Heroku.

Comment: How do I add the data from my development database to my production one?

Comment: Well, depending on how much data there is, it may be easiest just to copy it manually in heroku console.